# Connection to web server and reading XML files(Android)

Tags: android, xml, web-services

what I want to do is connect to a web server and can read an XML file
The exception is open failed erofs (read-only file system).
I added in the manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void getHTML() throws IOException {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http:/...");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader rd;
        String line;
        String name = "myfile.xml";
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        File file = new File(name);
        if(file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
            file = new File(name);
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getName(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            fw.write(line);
            fw.write("\n");
            //out.println(line);
            //out.flush();
        }
        fw.close();
        out.close();
        rd.close();
    }        
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can we see the Logcat please?

Comment: First of all, using `StrictMode` is not at all encouraged. You should do your networking Operations in a separate thread,..not in the main thread..

Answer (score 0):

I made changes and I solved.I'll post the correct code.

public void getHTML() throws IOException {

```
    FileOutputStream outputStream=null;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    String fullPath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http:..");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader rd;
        File dir = new File(fullPath.toString());
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(fullPath, "file.xml");
        if(file.exists())
            file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
        String line;
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String newline="\n";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
            outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
            outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
        }
        outputStream.close();
        rd.close();
    } 
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```